# In need of some code for the iphone SDK (Save an in app picture to your photos)

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, save

Im working on my first app for the apple app store and I am in need of the code to be able to see a picture and save it to the photos, also where the code goes, so some what of a tutorial of how to save a picture to the photos app, I am working with the latest version of the iphone SDK.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, (SEL)@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Here's [an example](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum).

Answer (score 0):

Referring "iPhone cookbook" by Erica Sadun